# Animals migrating north from Africa after meteor hit Earth - era of 'ice'

Tags: food, temperature, sea, ice

To eleborate on my question asked here - [Light Emitting Animals - What happens to the food chain?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40505/light-emitting-animals-what-happends-to-the-food-chain?noredirect=1#comment114860_40505)

where every animal has evolved / produced a light emitting organ.

Scenario - 200years after my first post - The world has started to cool down after a meteor hit the Earth, creating an ash / dust cloud as it evaporized into the atmosphere, which blocked most of the sunlight... the sea between africa and Europe has frozen solid over the last 10-25 years, and animals from Africa are starting to migrate North in search of new sources of food.

What impact would this have on the Apex Predators of Africa & their prey?

Comment: The meteor knocked the earth off its usual axis. Africa is now on the North Pole and eurasia on the equator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well ... they would most likely be dead.

Here's the thing: the Earth is warmest at the Equator. That's where plant life has the highest chances of surviving, which means it's where life would survive (herbivores eat plants, carnivores eat them).

Moving North makes no sense, as these animals would be walking over snow and ice for miles, and miles. With no food in sight how many of them would actually make it to the other side? Probably very few.

Once there they would find that the conditions are even worse than they were in Africa. At this point they would die regardless.

I'd also like to point out that the animals which are least capable to adapting to the cold, or who need the most energy to survive (carnivores) are far more likely to die out in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If the Apex predators have actually survived to this point (this sounds like a mass extinction event) they will follow their prey.  If the prey move north, the predators will follow, killing and eating the stragglers, the sick and the old.

Now why would the prey move north across a frozen sea?  Not a lot of reason since it is likely warmer where they are and have more plants possibly surviving.  Most moving North wouldn't like be able to make it across the Sahara Desert without starving or dying from dehydration.